# Select more values on clause IF in the stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a problem of syntax in my stored procedure when a select more values in my IF, on code snippet 37 OR 35.

```
IF 37 OR 35 NOT IN (SELECT CodPerfilSistema 
                    FROM [BRSAODB09].[ADMIN].[dbo].[PERFIL_USUARIO] 
                    WHERE CodUsuario = @pCodUsuario)
BEGIN
    SET @CondicaoEmpresa = ' AND [Lote].CodEmpresa = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodEmpresa);
    SET @CondicaoProjeto = ' AND [AUD_Projeto].CodProjeto = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodProjeto);
END
```

I tried the code above.

And below is how the code is running

```
 IF 37 NOT IN (SELECT CodPerfilSistema 
               FROM [BRSAODB09].[ADMIN].[dbo].[PERFIL_USUARIO] 
               WHERE CodUsuario = @pCodUsuario)
BEGIN
    SET @CondicaoEmpresa = ' AND [Lote].CodEmpresa = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodEmpresa);
    SET @CondicaoProjeto = ' AND [AUD_Projeto].CodProjeto = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodProjeto);
END
```

I need the permission for Id 37 and 35.

Comment: You really shouldn't be injecting the values of your parameters into your dynamic sql, you should be parametrising the `sp_executesql` statement

Comment: Also, are these variables strings? Are the columns strings? Strongly-typed parameters will avoid this problem altogether (its secondary purpose after security), but with the current code, you'll need to properly delimit the values.

Comment: Although others have guessed (apparently incorrectly), it's impossible to tell your intent from your broken code and the wording of your description.   I have no idea what this means:   "when a select more values in my IF, on code snippet 37 OR 35. / I need the permission for Id 37 and 35."   If you provide sample data and desired results, that might make the question clearer.

Comment: If you left out the working `35 not in ...` and simply had `if 37 begin ...` what would you expect?

Comment: I usually don't bother guessing when answering a question, but this seemed to be an easy guess. You should [edit] your question to [provide all the relevant details,](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info)

Answer (score 0):

try the below

```
IF not exists (SELECT * FROM [BRSAODB09].[ADMIN].[dbo].[PERFIL_USUARIO] where CodUsuario = @pCodUsuario
        and CodPerfilSistema in (37,35))
BEGIN
    SET @CondicaoEmpresa = ' AND [Lote].CodEmpresa = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodEmpresa);
    SET @CondicaoProjeto = ' AND [AUD_Projeto].CodProjeto = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), @pCodProjeto);
END
```

Comment: did not return anything.

Comment: As I dont have any idea about the data or other parts of the query, its hard to predict what you want. anyhow , I updated my answer by adding a not after the IF, as it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the help, I found a way to solve the problem I had.

It stayed like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
SELECT 1 
FROM [BRSAODB09].[ADMIN].[dbo].[PERFIL_USUARIO] 
WHERE CodUsuario = @pCodUsuario
AND  CodPerfilSistema IN(37,35)
)
BEGIN
     SET @CondicaoEmpresa = ' AND [Lote].CodEmpresa = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), 
     @pCodEmpresa);

     SET @CondicaoProjeto = ' AND [AUD_Projeto].CodProjeto = ' +  CONVERT(varchar(10), 
     @pCodProjeto);
END
```